# cardinality & column order in compound index (MySQL/InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I know the column order in a compound index matters if you want to query by a subset of the indexed-columns, but if you're query specifies values for all the indexed columns, is there any performance benefit to having a high-cardinality column earlier than a low-cardinality column? I vaguely remember reading something that suggested that was the case because it narrows down the result set quicker, but I can't find anything to back that up now.

I'm using MySQL w/ InnoDB. InnoDB uses clustered indexes, which might be relevant to my question, but I *think* it only does so for primary keys, which my index is not. The table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref_a_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ref_b_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_my_table_on_ref_a_ref_b_is_active` (`ref_a_id`, `ref_b_id`, `is_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2818259 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In relation to my question, imagine `ref_a_id` has a higher cardinality than `ref_b_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an old wives' tale that cardinality matters.

`INDEX(a,b)` and `INDEX(b,a)` perform virtually identically when in a BTree.  The depth of the BTree is the same.

What does matter is that *both* columns are searched with `=`, as in `WHERE a=12 AND b=45`.

The `PRIMARY KEY` in InnoDB is a BTree, and so is each secondary index.  The only difference is what *else* is in the leaf nodes.  The PK's leaf nodes contains *all* columns; a secondary index's leaf nodes contains the columns of the PK.

In InnoDB (not in some competing products), the PK is, by definition, clustered and `UNIQUE`.

As for your table,...

Are you allowing to rows for each ref_a--ref_b combo?  One 'active', one not?  This seems unlikely.

Why have `id` at all?  Why not promote the `UNIQUE` key to be the PK?

Is `is_active` ever `NULL`?

See my [*tips on many:many mapping tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).